# How to type Material UI Icon's fontSize prop?

Tags: typescript, material-ui, react-typescript

I've composed the component below, and I need to apply a type for the custom `iconFontSize` prop. How can I do this?

```
import { SvgIconComponent } from '@mui/icons-material'
import { Typography, TypographyProps} from '@mui/material'

type Props = TypographyProps & {
  Icon: SvgIconComponent
  iconFontSize: /* insert type here! */
}

export const IconTypography = ({
  Icon,
  iconFontSize = 'inherit',
  columnGap = 1,
  children,
  ...props
}: Props) => {
  return (
    <Typography display="flex" alignItems="center" columnGap={columnGap} {...props}>
      <Icon fontSize={iconFontSize} />
      {children}
    </Typography>
  )
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type `iconFontSize` as a union type of  'inherit' | 'large' | 'medium' | 'small':

```js
type Props = TypographyProps & {
  Icon: SvgIconComponent
  iconFontSize: "inherit" | "small" | "medium" | "large" 
}
```

If you want to use the exact type from the MUI type definition file, you can alternatively use:

```js
import { OverridableStringUnion } from '@mui/types';

fontSize?: OverridableStringUnion<
  'inherit' | 'large' | 'medium' | 'small',
  SvgIconPropsSizeOverrides
>;
```

The `OverridableStringUnion` type is in turn defined as such:

```js
export type OverridableStringUnion<T extends string | number, U = {}> = GenerateStringUnion<
  Overwrite<Record<T, true>, U>
>;
```

See the type definition in the MUI docs here: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/svg-icon/